# Best way of sending multiple http requests at the same time when collect data from websites

Tags: python

I collect datas from a website for AI training by Python. I send requests to indexes of a website respectively.  After parsing the html, if i find a meaningful data for my purpose in the html, I save it and send request to another index.
There are more than 5 million websites that should be checked. So I think i should send multiple request at a time. Else, I can't finish them.

I am looking for best way to send multiple request at the same time. I know the ways: thread, multiple python scripts, async functions. But I am not sure about the best way.

Thank you.

Comment: this is an opinion-based question unfortunately and is not well suited for this site

Comment: You can give your ideas. Which site is relation about the question?

Comment: this is an I/O bound task but there's lots of context behind it and nuances that only you know. so typically for I/O bound tasks you want either multi-threading or async. now it's up to you to research both methods and see what is better suited for you

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Requests Futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures), its a very simple async wrapper of Requests, you can use it as follows:

```py
from concurrent.futures import as_completed
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

with FuturesSession() as session:
    futures = [session.get(url) for url in urls]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        res = future.result()
        print(res.json())
```